# Retrieving timestamp from mysql row upon creation of new row entry

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp

Is this valid?

```
    <?php
        $timestamp = mysql_query("INSERT INTO column1 (entry1, entry2) 
                                  VALUES ('$entry1', '$entry2') 
                                  AND SELECT timestamp");
    ?>
```

timestamp is a mysql column which generates a timestamp upon row creation.

e.g. 
-do I need to specify creation of "timestamp" row? (I think it is okay, configured to do it on its own)
-can these two actions be executed within the same query? if not, how can I do it? I want to make sure that I get the timestamp, as I use it later in the code also as a unique identifier as this entry. how can I otherwise get it? (assuming there may be entries which are multiple and similar in many of the other row entries).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I depends on what you need the info for. If you need it to be stored against other rows/entities and you want it to be consistent then I would store the date in PHP (possible once per request in a web app) and then use that throughout, e.g.

```
$currentTimestamp = time();
$timestamp = mysql_query("INSERT INTO column1 (entry1, entry2, timestamp_col) 
                              VALUES ('$entry1', '$entry2', $currentTimestamp);
```

That way everywhere you use the timestamp it will be consistent. Your request doesn't have to take seconds for the timestamp to vary within it.

Even if you're not storing it against anything else you still might want to use this method if you need to retrieve that info as the only other way is two queries and this would most likely be more efficient.

That doesn't mean it never makes sense to auto-populate a MySQL date field as it you're just logging that info for retrieving later then it of course makes sense to do it within MySQL.

Comment: okay this is great thanks, what data type should I use for this column? I tried it before this way but it all came out as zeros... must have used the wrong datatype, so I thought to change it, but I agree - youre right, this is probably the best way.

Comment: See your other question about date formats! Personally I'd use MySQL's DATETIME format (and make sure you format the unix timestamp appropriately in the example above).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid mysql statement. As an option you could use PHP function instead.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO column1 (entry1, entry2) VALUES ('$entry1', '$entry2')";
$timestamp = mysql_query($sql) ? time() : null;
```

Comment: Okay I see, I'll use a handle, good call. thanks.. but isn't there a risk that the timestamp might be off by a milisecond between the php and the mysql generating them?

Comment: Yes, I thik it's possible. If miliseconds matter to you, you could add another field to your table with TIMESTAMP data type and DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP option. But in this case you'll need to use another query to retrieve that time from the row you've inserted.

Comment: yes but how can I retrieve that time? this is exactly my question.. how do I know that I am retrieving the right entry? :(

Answer (score 1):

No, that isn't a valid syntax.

One alternative is to assign now() to a variable and use that in the timestamp column instead of the value automatically generated.

```
set @now = now();
insert into your_table (timestamp_column) values (@now);
select @now();
```

Comment: that's what I was considering doing. but I was thinking of `time();` what's the difference between `now` and `time`? (I tried time but it gave me all zeros. how am I supposed to define the column in this case? int? varchar? with how much space?) thanks!

Comment: Timestamp is fine. You can assign a timestamp column any valid date value (1970-2034 or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the timestamp value exactly that is in your timestamp cell, you have to get insert id and then use that last insert id to get the time stamp for that id. 
Lets say,

```
$query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO my_table("username","password") VALUES("falcon","test") ');
$last_id = mysql_insert_id($query);  // This gets your id of the row inserted by $query
$timstamp = mysql_query('SELECT timestamp FROM my_table where id = "'.$last_id.'"')
```