# Setting column DATA TYPE for Timestamp, from PHP to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, types, timestamp

I'm using '$timestamp=time();' function in php to set the current time.

Anyway - What should I use for this column's definition in mysql? is it int? something else? and how much space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does have a native [DateTime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) type which you can use, or else you can store the unix timestamp as an INT. There are subtle differences between the two. If you want to do any date manipulation in your queries (such as retrieving all entries in the last week) then MySQL's native column type is probably best. Either way you may need to think about how you handle timezones - even if you don't think it's relevant now it may well be further down the line (just handling DST for example). There is a whole book on handling dates and times in PHP ([PHPArch book on Date and Time](http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-date-and-time-programming/)). I haven't read it (yet!) myself but Derrick Rethans, the author, knows pretty much everything there is to know on the subject.

Comment: thanks, I am aware of it, but wanted specifically to do it through the php function. you raised good points too. anyhow I understand your answer is INT then?

Comment: do you know how long should it should be set to?

Comment: Depends on what range of dates you need to be able to handle. I'm pretty sure an UNSIGNED INT will handle all the values a PHP unix timestamp can handle on a 32-bit system. If you want to go further than that or you're using PHP's DateTime classes you might need to check. MySQL's DATE fields can handle pretty much any date in the future.

Comment: Hey, update: I tried DATE and it didn't work (saved a bunch of zeros instead of the timestamp). I'm using INT and it seems to be working fine. Thanks!

Comment: If you use the DATE field you need to format the date as YYYY-MM-DD before sending it to MySQL. For DATETIME fields, it's YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

Answer (score 0):

In case you wish to include the time of an insert/update query into the mysql database, you can do that directly with MySQL. this link should help. [Click Here](http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/CREATE-TABLE-examples.html). For the solution to your problem check the content under the subhead- **Creating a table with the current timestamp**. All the best.

Comment: I know, I want specifically to use php. see here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623868/retrieving-timestamp-from-mysql-row-upon-creation-of-new-row-entry) Thanks for the reference, I'm checking it out.